# Getting issue when convert c# code to PHP as below

Tags: c#, php

I am running this code:

```cs
var timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
var sharedSecret = "xx";
var saltedString = timeStamp.ToString("2021-01-07T16:42:33.619667Z") + sharedSecret;

//Encoding saltedString using Unicode little-endian byte order
byte[] encodedSaltedString = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(saltedString);

//Hashing Algorithm used is SHA512
HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA512Managed();

//Compute Hash of encodedSaltedString
byte[] hashedEncodedString = hash.ComputeHash(encodedSaltedString);

//Convert hashed array to base64-encoded string
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedEncodedString);
```

I am then getting this result in C#:
"gQhjrLnY6fo44EeaaWaUBE1PY/8oEIRsUcK3AMSCVUCYMM4vRfxvQEEggXaHTF0GQbw4w2HbWArX1k6NnkzJFg=="

I converted to this code as below, but I am getting an issue. Can I get some help on this?

```php
$timestamp = "2021-01-07T16:42:33.619667Z";
$sharedSecret = 'xx';
$saltedString = $timestamp.$sharedSecret;

$utf=mb_convert_encoding($saltedString, "UTF-16LE");

$signature = base64_encode(hash('sha512', $utf));
```

IN PHP I am getting this result:
`ODEwODYzYWNiOWQ4ZTlmYTM4ZTA0NzlhNjk2Njk0MDQ0ZDRmNjNmZjI4MTA4NDZjNTFjMmI3MDBjNDgyNTU0MDk4MzBjZTJmNDVmYzZmNDA0MTIwODE3Njg3NGM1ZDA2NDFiYzM4YzM2MWRiNTgwYWQ3ZDY0ZThkOWU0Y2M5MTY=`

But both should be same. The c# one is correct, I want the same in the php code as well.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: What exactly does "_and its not working_" mean? Empty page? Wrong result? Any errors?

Comment: @brombeer Wrong result getting? Is this correct conversion?

Comment: Tested, I am getting what looks like a `SHA` hash -- I don't see an issue?  What is your expected result, and what result are you getting instead?

Comment: Beware your C# DateTime contains fractional seconds and the PHP one doesn't. Also `:` in a C# DateTime format string means the [current culture's time separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator), not the literal string `:`: you probably want to quote it: `':'`. It's unlikely that this is causing your issue however (whatever that issue is)

Comment: Of course you will get different results back from both snippets: they're salted by the current (fractional) time, so you'll get different results if you run the same code twice in either language

Comment: Right, after your edit, my comment above applies: the code is **obviously** salted by the current date, including seconds, so if you run it twice you will get different results. You'll have to run both snippets at **exactly** the same instance to get the same output, and that's not practically possible

Comment: @canton7 I edited the question and added the result of both. C# one is correct but not get the same in the PHP. Now I added the same time in both the code snippet

Comment: Also note that PHP's `hash` function returns lower-case hexits by default, whereas C#'s is returning bytes, which is responsible for the length difference. Use `hash('sha512', $utf, true)` to get the same length output. I found that by glancing at the PHP manual for `hash`, which is something you should always do

Comment: No, you did not add the same time in both snippets. That would be `$timestamp = '2021-01-07T16:42:33.619667Z'`, with no call to `gmdate`, and likewise `var saltedString = "2021-01-07T16:42:33.619667Z" + sharedSecret;` in C#.

Comment: @canton7 that by mistake I added here but in real code it is not just edited the questions. see now.

Comment: @canton7 Use hash('sha512', $utf, true) this works can you add this as answer so I can accept this?

Comment: @TusharMaru I've worked on the timestamp part; if you want me to add another another (besides canton7) let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP docs for `hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php):

> ```php
> hash ( string $algo , string $data , bool $binary = false ) : string|false
> ```
>
> binary
>    When set to true, outputs raw binary data. false outputs lowercase hexits.

You're not passing a value for `$binary`, so it's returning a string of hexadecimal characters.

The C# [`HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_ComputeHash_System_Byte___) method on the other hand binary data.

Since you're base64-encoding the result, you're presumably expecting the hash function to return binary data. You therefore need to pass `true` as the value for `$binary`:

```php
$signature = base64_encode(hash('sha512', $utf, true));
```